# C++ / CannyEdgeDetection.exe has stop working Codeblocks /OpenCV Error: Assertion failed

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a big problem with my canny edge sample. A few days ago it was working but recently I don't know why, when I use a program which reads my webcam it doesn't work.

[Here's the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDqbj.png)

This is my sample :

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;


    Mat edges;
    namedWindow("edges",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
        Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
        imshow("edges", edges);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I really don't know what is happening, because I use the same sample, but it decide to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

That assertion checks if your input into `cvtColor` contains 3 or 4 channels. Either camera didn't recover the data, in which case `cout << frame.size();` should print `[0 x 0]` onto a console, or  your camera doesn't produce a BGR image. You can check number of channels by calling `frame.channels()`.

If `frame.size()` returns `[0 x 0]`, then your camera is either disabled by an OS, used by another program or there's a compatibilty issue with OpenCV. You should check wheter it's working with other programs.

Otherwise if your channel count is 1, it means that your camera is already getting gray image and you should ommit the conversion. I don't think OpenCV supports capture methods with other channel counts, but I might be wrong.